# Dynamically get the length of a Vimeo Video via PHP

Tags: php, vimeo

I found a function from Stack to get the length of a Vimeo video which works fine with a Video ID provided on the original code but does not seem to work when I change it...

Can anyone help?

The function:

```
function vimeoVideoDuration($video_url) {
    $video_id = (int)substr(parse_url($video_url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
    $json_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $video_id . '.xml';
    $ch = curl_init($json_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    if (!isset($data->video->duration)) {
        return null;
    }

    $duration = $data->video->duration;
    return $duration;
}
```

When I `echo vimeoVideoDuration('https://vimeo.com/115134273');` the amount of seconds for that video works brilliantly.

However, if I change that to my own video ID I get several errors in my error log... I have provided these below:

```
[02-Nov-2016 12:57:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in /manage/view-module.php on line 28
[02-Nov-2016 12:57:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): 149029246 not found. in /manage/view-module.php on line 28
[02-Nov-2016 12:57:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /manage/view-module.php on line 28
[02-Nov-2016 12:57:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /manage/view-module.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 /manage/view-module.php(28): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('149029246 not f...', 16384)
#1 /manage/view-module.php(51): vimeoVideoDuration('https://vimeo.c...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /manage/view-module.php on line 28
```

Comment: Have you checked the response that you're getting from the curl call?

Comment: @PatrickQ I found that if I change the privacy setting to 'Anyone' can view this video it works however I need it hidden on Vimeo as it's a course video which people pay for on my website and I don't want people finding them free. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that function uses the old Simple API (note the format: `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/*`) which can only be used with videos public on vimeo.com.

If the video has embed anywhere privacy, you can use oEmbed to retrieve the embed code and duration. Documentation for that can be found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

(EDIT: oEmbed can also be used on domain-level privacy videos!)

If the video is private and has domain-level privacy, you'll need to create an API app on the Vimeo Developer site and authenticate your requests to the data API. Docs here:

- https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start
- https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec
- https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

You can also find the official PHP library here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries